# xeCJK and paragraph indentation

Tags: xetex, indentation, xecjk

I am using xelatex and want to use the xeCJK package, but without indenting the first paragraph of a section. I tried the setup directive below, which should do the trick. But it does not. The manual is in Chinese ...

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\xeCJKsetup{indentfirst=false}


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

I want to have a paragrpah without indentation.

This one should be indented.

\subsection{Section 2}

Same here.

This one should be indented.


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the log file you find this warning:

```
*************************************************
* xeCJK warning: "option-invalid"
* 
* The `indentfirst' option only can be set in the optional argument to the
* \usepackage command when xeCJK is being loaded.
* 
* Please do not set it via the \xeCJKsetup command.
*************************************************
```

which is self-explanatory: do

```
\usepackage[indentfirst=false]{xeCJK}
```

Be warned that languages loaded with Polyglossia may revert the setting (Italian, for instance).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the answer! I got into the same problem. Because there is something different now, I put the new situation here. In the new package, it gives the new warning as follow.

```
*************************************************
* xeCJK warning: "option-deprecated"
*
* The `indentfirst' option is deprecated.
* You may load the package `indentfirst' after xeCJK to use its function.
*
*************************************************
```

So the setting should be changed. Now, it suggests using the `indentfirst` package instead of the setting in `xeCJK`. The following code is advised now.

```
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}  % setting the indentation to be two Chinese characters size.
```